# The "general algorithm" for primary decomposition

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to learn the process of *primary decomposition of a **monomial ideal*** and struggling. I can't seem to find a resource where I'm able to follow the steps in an example and see the thinking behind them. If, say, we have the ideal $I=\langle x^2, xy, x^2z^2,yz^2\rangle$, the first step I take is to write down the intersection of 8 ideals (can anyone define what the intersection of two ideals actually is?), along the lines of $$I=\langle x^2, x, x^2,y\rangle \cap \langle x^2, y, x^2, y\rangle \cap  \dots$$

I'm not sure what the next step is... I start taking the "repeats" out but I'm not sure what the criteria is or what I'm looking for. Can anyone take me through the steps in actually finding a primary decomposition, or point me in the direction of a paper which brings it back down to a basic level? Really lost right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book "Monomial Ideals" by *Herzog-Hibi*, Section 1-3:
Theorem 1.3.1 and Example 1.3.3 are (probably) what you want. I add image of Theorem  and part of proof:

[image]

.
.
.
Note that by Corollary 1.3.2, A monomial ideal is irreducible if and only if it is generated by pure powers of the variables.
As authors say: *The proof of Theorem 1.3.1 shows us how we can find such a presentation. The following example illustrates the procedure.*

[image]

---

$$
I=(x^2, xy, x^2z^2,yz^2)= \\
(x^2, xy, yz^2)=\\ 
(x^2, x, yz^2)\cap (x^2, y, yz^2)=\\
(x,yz^2)\cap (x^2, y)=\\
(x,y)\cap (x,z^2) \cap (x^2, y)=\\
(x,z^2) \cap (x^2, y)
$$

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! In the final example, whats the reasoning behind getting rid of the $(x^2,y)$? Is it because the radical of $(x,y)$ and $(x^2,y)$ are equal?

Comment: You are welcome. typo corrected. $(x,y)\cap  (x^2, y)=(x^2, y),$ because $(x^2, y)\subseteq (x, y)$