# Primary decomposition of monomial ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Still trying to get a full understanding of primary decomposition, I had the ideal  $$I=\langle x^3, x^2z^2, y^4, xy^3, x^2y^2\rangle$$

Using the method the user in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277860/the-general-algorithm-for-primary-decomposition) post I posted yesterday, I've got to a stage where I have 
$$(y^4,x) \cap (x^2,y^3) \cap (z^2,y^4,x) \cap (z^2,y^3,x^2) \cap (x^3,z^2,y^2)$$

I'm not sure where to go from here, what can I "remove" and whats the reasoning behind doing so?

Comment: Go to $I=(y^4,x) \cap (x^2,y^3) \cap (x^3,z^2,y^2)$, cause you learned that $A\subseteq B\implies A\cap B=A$. Now notice that all these three ideals are primary, and the first two have the same radical.

Comment: Excuse my slowness, but I'm not following quite how $(x^3, z^2, y^2) \subseteq (z^2, y^3, x^2)$ and $(x^3, z^2, y^2) \subseteq (z^2,y^4,x)$? I presume your answer is the primary decomposition, would the associated primes of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/I$ be $(x,y)$ and $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: Did I say that? It looks much more likely to have $(y^4,x)\subseteq  (z^2,y^4,x)$.

Comment: Ohhh... so in the same vein $(x^2,y^3) \subseteq (z^2,y^3,x^2)$ so we can get rid of it? Is this the same reasoning behind, say, $(x) \cap (z^2,x) = (x)$?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. And yes, the associated primes are those you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!